# while using my css class in bootstrap not working

Tags: html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a website using bootstrap,so while making navigation menus of home,about,etc and trying to give top margin using my own built css class,but its showing now effect even after using my css class, what's the problem,please help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk48B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if you need borders then Try using Borders rather than using Margin
Eg: border-bottom:10px

regards
Kiran

Comment: I have placed fluid container at top,an have placed logo just below the container but i want to move logo bit closer to the container and trying to use my css class but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If I can see well, your problem is that you have

> my name.

a class have to be together, something like:

> my-name